# When purchasing VMware Workstation, do you actually get the box AND a physical CD?

Tags: vmware-workstation

I was wondering when purchasing VMware Workstation, do you actually get the box AND a physical CD that it shows in the picture on the add-to-cart page?

Answer (score 0):

No.  You download it.  When you purchase it, you are emailed a receipt that includes the license key.  They never update the software (as in release patches or fixes).  Each new release within a particular version is a complete new install.  Each new install within a particular version removes the old version and then installs the new release.  Configuration data is retained, so it "feels" like a patch even though it's a remove and re-install process.

For example, if you have Workstation version 10 and they update it to version 10.1, you will be be able download 10.1 and run the install program.  This will remove version 10 and install version 10.1.  Your existing licensing does not change and you are not asked to re-enter your license.  You might be asked to re-enter your license if you remove version 10 from the control panel (as opposed to the install program that comes with version 10.1) and then run the install.

The only time you have to pay additional money is if you upgrade (as opposed to update) from one version to the next, like from version 10 to version 11.  Currently, you can upgrade from a version to a newer version (like from 10 to 11 or 10 to 12) for some discount off the price of the version you are buying.  At some point, you just start all over and pay the full retail (except for any promotions that may be going on).  So you probably wouldn't be able to upgrade from version 5 to version 12.5 and take advantage of any upgrade discount.

Each time you buy a new version you are entitled to some period of free support.  It's not that long, 30 to 60 days if I recall.  After that, you're either on your own (relying on support forums) or you can buy support.

Their site requires you to register and once registered, you have access to their online license manager.  Of course, you should keep your license key somewhere safe, but VMware always has a copy that you can access by logging in with your registered account.  So if you lose your machine and records of your purchase (i.e. you're left with nothing), you can still download, install and license the version you paid for, all through their site.

Comment: There are boxed versions of VMware that exist

Comment: @Ramhound I checked with VMware.  Their email response regarding the availability of a boxed version of Workstation : "Sorry for the delayed response. It is my understanding that it is only available online and not as a physical media buy."  Furthermore, in the document Using VMware Workstation Pro for version 12 (http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-12/topic/com.vmware.ICbase/PDF/workstation-pro-12-user-guide.pdf) it states (page 21): "The Workstation Pro installation software is in the file that you downloaded and the license key is sent to
you in email."  There is no mention of a CD or DVD.

Comment: The question was asked 2 years before VMWare Workstation 12.1 was released.  In any event, I have seen retail boxes in retail stores, for past versions.  I have no idea what you actually asked, I suspect the response was based on the fact, VMWare themselfs do not sell (physical) retail copies to customers only and only distrubute the installer  online.

Comment: @Ramhound,  I just got a 2nd email from VMWare: "Folks I was forwarded on this email stream and  VMware stopped with physical product for Workstation and Fusion about 3 years ago, box product,  ie. CD or USB stick download only. 

Hope this helps. 
 
Mtb
 
 
Michael T. Butler
Director, Global eCommerce
[I removed his contact info]

Answer (score -1):

VMware Workstation is software that allows you to utilize virtualization and create virtual machines, it is not a physical machine. Please see [this VMware](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/) page for detailed information about VMware Workstation. If you want to try a sample of it before purchasing, I would recommend trying VMware Player, which is a significant step down from VMware Workstation, but it also allows you to create Virtual Machines also. They do offer demos of VMware Workstation too, but if you like VMware Player, that might fit your needs as well. VMware Workstation allows a lot more control.

Comment: I'm aware of it's purpose. I'm just asking if it comes with a CD to install it from.

Comment: Every time I have used it as a VMware partner with my company (data center), I just download it. I have not purchased it as a consumer (non-business). I assume you would just download it. Sorry for providing an answer that was not helpful to you. Your initial question was not clean enough. Perhaps you should ask their sales department, things like that are likely to change over time.

Comment: Understandable. Thanks for the support. But, do you know how many licenses you get? What if my computer's HD fails, am I out of luck with my license? It is great software and I need it.

Comment: I don't know that much about the licensing of the software. I used it as a lab one time, then uninstalled it. Again, I would ask their support about the purchasing and licensing of the product.